# Quering an array from another table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this query:

```
SELECT `beacons`.*, `blocks`.`ID` AS `blockID` FROM (`beacons`) LEFT JOIN `blocks` ON `blocks`.`StoreID` = `beacons`.`Major` WHERE `beacons`.`Major` = '2' ORDER BY `beacons`.`Minor` desc
```

When I do it I get reptitive information from the table `beacons`

[image: reptitive info - besides <code>blocksID</code> everything is the same]

What I want to get instead - one row with an array of blocks ID:
[image: One row with an array of blocks ID - to save time and resources by reptitive results table.]

Comment: Could you explain further/clarify? Read this a couple of times and it's very hard to understand what you're actually asking?

Answer (score 1):

[image: SQL Joins] Your question (i think) refers to INNER JOIN, which is shown below (amongst others). It also comes with a little bit of SQL for each one :)

Answer (score 0):

Look into the [INNER JOIN](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-inner-join.aspx) function.

Comment: Thank you. now I got this Query:

SELECT `beacons`.*, `blocks`.`ID` AS `blockID` FROM (`beacons`) LEFT JOIN `blocks` ON `blocks`.`BeaconID` = `beacons`.`ID` WHERE `beacons`.`ID` = '2' ORDER BY `beacons`.`Minor` desc

Comment: This query makes many rows with the whole info of the beacon again and again, and for each time the only change is the block ID, instead of this repetitive rows I want an array of all of the block IDs in one line - instead of many rows. is that possible?

Comment: You are going to have to format your query results into the desired structure after you retrieve them through your codebase.